# How to determine RAM usage of a query

Tags: mysql, memory

What are the factors that would affect the RAM usage by a query?

How do I assess the rough RAM usage of a query given the complete SQL?

This is regarding the MySQL RDBMS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL uses RAM in many ways...

- For caching data and indexes.  In some sense, it does not matter how much RAM, since it is *cache*.  This may be the biggest use, but it is a "shared" use.
- A complex `SELECT` may need a temporary table (eg, for `GROUP BY` and/or `ORDER BY` and/or subquery).  This may be done in RAM, or it may not even attempt to do it in RAM, but instead do it on disk.  There is one setting that puts a limit on the size of each in-memory temp table.
- The parsing of the statement takes a little bit of RAM.
- The `binlog` is buffered through RAM.
- "Group commit" is buffered in RAM.
- Galera does its "will this commit with a deadlock" logic in RAM.
- InnoDB uses bits to keep track of what is locked.

Shall I go on?  Your question is not easy to answer.  Furthermore, I would argue that it is mostly irrelevant.  Would you care to explain why you asked?

Comment: Rick, Thank you for your answer. One of our instances started using RAM all at sudden after running successfully for 100 days. During that time, we have observed a complex query on the query prompt. I just wanted to know whether it can b a reason or not. Your reply is nice enough for me. It would be my strong reference going forward while dealing with this like issues.